# totally portable ubuntu installation on flash drive?

Tags: usb, drive

is it possible to install ubuntu on a flash drive so that i can essentially plug it into any computer and have my desktop, software and files there ready and waiting for me and doesn't leave anything on the PC i was using once it is unplugged?

If it can, can anyone point me towards a guide for doing this please. thanks for the help in advance.

I've never properly used linux before so i apologize if this is a noob question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net) for putting Ubuntu on a flash drive. Just select an amount of megabytes of "persistence" that will store data through reboots.

Comment: This approach is not as nice as A. Dueppen's, but you can take a live iso and push the directory structure to to your USB drive.  You have to make the drive bootable for it to work.

And thanks, A. Dueppen, this is a solution for another problem that I have that I wasn't even thinking of fixing this way - my OS disk died.